# C# SortedDictionary producing unusual results - Mk2

Tags: c#, sorteddictionary

I don't think I posted enough detail in the previous question and people seemed to stop responding so I'm reposting as we need to know why this problem is happening

I'm working with a SortedDictionary and when we loop through it we get odd results.

there is a lot of nesting involved and the final dictionary is actually the child of another dictionary which is the child of another!

is the the complete nest.

```
SortedDictionary<String, SortedDictionary<String, SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<String, String>>>>()
```

The dictionary i'm looping through is

```
SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<String, String>>
```

And Here is the loop:

```
foreach (SortedDictionary<String, String> cDic in openTrades.Values)
{
    String cTimestamp = convertTimestamp(cDic["open"]);
    if (!closeTrades.ContainsKey(cDic["key"]) && barArray.ContainsKey(cDic["pair"]))
    {
          foreach (SortedDictionary<String, String> bDic in barArray[cDic["pair"]][cDic["frame"]].Values)
          {
               //This is the relative Loop
          }
    }
}
```

barArray is our Primary SortedDictionary (the subject of this question)
openTrades is another SortedDictionary

Now when we loop through the dictionary with an integer as an index we get varied results - IE. if we have 1,2,3,4 as the keys when looping through it may present them in this order: 4,2,1,3 which clearly doesn't make sense as this is meant to be a sorted dictionary.

Any help as quickly as possible would be greatly appreciated as im stumped on this issue.
Thanks
James

Comment: It looks to me as if you should be able to come up with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem but which *doesn't* need all this nesting.

Comment: Can you explain more like the implementation of barArray and openTrades

Comment: The reason i've added the nesting is because in it's simplest form - this works just fine, but when it's nested it doesn't!

Navid What more explanation do you need?

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that you are misinterpreting the results that you are seeing. In the loop that you show, you are not looping through the int key, you are looping through the list of values. Thus, you have no way to determine in which order the int keys are actually returned.

You probably have something in the SortedDictionary itself, that should indicate which int from the enclosing dictionary it belongs to. I would imagine, that there is some bug in how you are forming these values, so that the int in the key does not actually match the value.

I suggest to narrow the issue down, that you foreach through `openTrade`s and not `openTrades.Values`. This way you'll be able to see the real keys in the returned KeyValuePair. I'm pretty sure they will appear sorted.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but when the dictionary isn't nested the same loop works perfectly however when it's nested that's when we see an issue

Comment: I didn't suggest changing anything about nesting. I just offered a way to modify your foreach loop, so the functionality of your code stays the same, but you have a better chance at understanding what's happening because you have an additional information of the current "real" key.

Comment: The "Real key" is created before the data is added into the sorted dictionary - then forms the Key and a value in the final dictionary.

However I tried used a KeyValuePair and I get the same results it is iterating through the dictionary incorrectly

Comment: Can you post your modified code, where you iterate with KeyValuePair, and dump the Key from the key value pair somewhere (file, console, error log, whatever is simplest for you) and post the dump here, so we can see both the code that is dumping the key and the result of the dump. Also might help to create a small repro that we could run that would demonstrate the problem, but I'm guessing the posting the logging code and the log will be easier.